# How to programmatically scroll a SurfaceScatterView

Tags: scroll, itemscontrol, pixelsense, scatterview

The SurfaceScatterView is an ItemControl,
I want to scroll it into a position that I choose,
Can any one help ,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved ,
ScrollToHorizontalOffset(double d)
ScrollToVerticalOffset(double d)